# Poker side pots and dead money

Tags: rules, all-in, side-pots

I m wondering something about side pots calculation. I m gonna explain with an example to make it clear:

Player 1 (stack 100) |
Player 2 (stack 100) |
Player 3 (stack 25)

**--- Flop**
Player 3 goes all in for 25 |
Player 1 calls 25 |
Player 2 calls 25 too

**--- Turn**
Both players 1 and 2 check

**--- River**
Player 1 goes all in |
Player 2 fold

My question is: If player 3 wins the hand, does he win 75 (player 3 all in + players 1/2 calls) or 50 (only player 3 all in + player 1 call) ? Considering player 2 has fold on the river whereas he called player 3 all in with 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Player three wins the money from the other players that match player three's money.

In this case player three is going to get the main pot, which is seventy five. That is twenty five from player one, twenty five from player two and player three's original betting.

Player one or two only wins the seventy five in the main pot if he can show down a better hand than player three. Player three has a hand that can no longer be bet out of that pot.

Player one and two had engaged in more betting, on the side, and player three could have none of it nor could player three lose the main pot unless one or two showed a better hand. Once betting is on the side, the all-in player has nothing to do with that. For the side it is like player three is not even there, his stake is only in the main pot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, if I understand well, a short-stacked player can earn more than a double up if, in the example, more than one player called the all-in and then one of these players has fold.

Comment: If he goes all in for 25, he covers the first 25 from *each* of his opponents, so if there are 10 players in the pot, he can win 250.

Comment: @Rotan Plus even if you're only heads up against a single player, if there are antes and blinds, those could also contribute to slightly more than a double-up if you win.

Answer (score 0):

The main pot is 75 and goes to player 3

The fold of 75 side pot is between player 1 and 2 only
That side pot would just go back to player 1 when player 2 folded

So player 1 did player 3 a favor by pushing 2 off the hand

From the perspective of player 1 there is no fold equity to that final bet

In a tournament (especially in the money) you will often see few bets after a short stack is all in as it benefits everyone to bust a short stack out.  If I have a made hand (but not a monster) it makes less sense for me to push a draw off the pot with a big bet as if the draw hits it would likely take out the short stack. It makes more sense for a made hand to chances losing a small pot and also take out the short stack. Draws that hit and value bet on the river to a checked down pot to some is poor etiquette.

Comment: there is no side pot, IE only if the bet is called is their a side pot,

Comment: @Jon Player 1 went all in.  That 75 bet went into a side pot.    And when player 2 folded THAT side pot went back to player 1 - he did not get the money player 2 had bet before folding.  If you want to  call that a side bet rather then side pot - fine.  Player 1 does not get what player 2 bet before the fold.